# PostgreSQL запрос с IF

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT cast(json_extract_path_text(json_array_elements(:userRoles::json),'role','value ') as integer)
```

Если он вернет значение равной 1, то выполнить запрос характера:

```
SELECT EXISTS
( 
    SELECT 1 FROM sec_user_role r
      WHERE r.user_id = 1
      AND r.role_id = 1

)
```

Он должен вернуть `false` или `true`.

Если  первый `SELECT` с массива вернет другое значение, не равное 1, то всегда возвращать `true`.

Comment: И в чем собственно проблема, что вам мешает в ваш второй запрос добавить `AND cast(...)!=1` ?

Comment: что именно и как именно? не силен я в синтаксисе sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можете использовать такой способ (не протестирован):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN magic_number.res = 1 
    THEN ( SELECT EXISTS
        ( 
            SELECT 1 FROM sec_user_role r
              WHERE r.user_id = 1
              AND r.role_id = 1
        )
    )
    ELSE true        
FROM
( SELECT cast(
    json_extract_path_text(
        json_array_elements(:userRoles::json),'role','value ') 
    AS integer) AS res ) AS magic_number;
```

Comment: да, он работает. Спасибо. тут :userRoles это json '[{"party":{"value":null},"role":{"value":"1","label":"Оператор"}}]'